# Git deleting files without using git rm

Tags: git, git-add, git-rm

Often I'll delete a file (via Finder) while dealing with merge conflicts. When I go to conclude my merge, I try `git rm my_file.txt` and I get an error that `fatal: unable to stat 'my_file.txt': No such file or directory`.

Do I have to go to the CLI and always do `git rm my_file.txt`, or is there a git trick where I can mark that the file I just deleted should be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `git add .`  On that folder after you have deleted the file in your finder and git will mark the file as deleted

Comment: This won't always work depending on the version of git you're using. I forgot which version changed how `git add` works so that it also stages removed files. If `git add .` doesn't stage the deleted files, then `git add -A` should work.